# Flutter Web: I'm getting XMLHttpRequest error on API calls

Tags: php, flutter, api, flutter-web

I'm working on a simple project with Flutter web. When I try any API Call on my back-end I'm getting an error like 'Error: XMLHttpRequest error.'
I did some research and found out that it is related to CORS.

This is the final version of my code in PHP.

```
<?php

header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

require_once("connect.php");
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM feedback ORDER BY id DESC") -> fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);  

?>
```

My Flutter code for making API call

```
List? feedbackList;

  getFeedbacks() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('myDomainUrl/get.php');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print('RESPONSE REPONSE RESPONSE RESPONSE: ${response.statusCode}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        feedbackList = json.decode(response.body);
      });
      return feedbackList;
    }
  }
```

It works on mobile but somehow I'm still getting same error on Web.

Answer (score 4):

try adding this line to the headers of your response from the backend

```
<?php

header('access-control-allow-origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
...

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS is an issue exclusive to browsers, and not mobile apps. This is why it works fine on mobile. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/13558035) to perhaps fix your CORS issue in PHP.

If you can't solve it, you can build your web app using `html renderer` instead of canvas kit.

Comment: Even using HTML renderer doesn't work. Still getting the same error..